# how to use bcrypt compare function

Tags: javascript, bcrypt

I 'm having a problem with the compare function in b crypt, I have a salt password I can not get it to compare password to the encrypted password in the database here is my code...

```
router.post('/login', (req, res) => {
let userName = req.body.userName;
let password = req.body.password;

connection.query(
SELECT_ALL_USERS_QUERY + ' WHERE userName=?',
[userName],
(err, results, fields) => {
  if (results[0].password) {
    bcrypt.compare(password, results[0].password, (err, result) => {
      console.log(password);
      console.log(results[0].password);
      if (result) {
        res.send();
      } else {
        return res.status(400).send();
      }
    });
  }
}
);
});

router.post('/add', (req, res) => {
const {
firstName = req.body.firstName,
lastName = req.body.lastName,
userName = req.body.userName,
password = req.body.password,
email = req.body.email
} = req.query;
const salt = 16;

bcrypt.hash(password, salt, (err, hashPass) => {
if (err) throw err;
const INSERT_USERS_QUERY =
  'INSERT INTO users (' +
  'firstName, lastName, userName, password, email) values(' +
  `'${firstName}','${lastName}','${userName}','${hashPass}','${email}')`;

connection.query(INSERT_USERS_QUERY, (err, results) => {
  if (err) {
    return res.send(err);
  } else {
    return res.send('Successfuly added user');
  }
});
});
});
```

can anyone help me..

Comment: Can you show the log error?

Comment: are you comparing the right passwords?  Looks like you are taking password from the form (e.g. 'mypassword') but comparing it to an encrypted password (what you saved).  console log both req.body.password and your hashPass to double check

Comment: I get this error Fetch.jsx:15 POST http://localhost:4000/users/login?userName=owendani1964&password=dad84 404 (Not Found)

Comment: what happens if you just goto localhost... that error says your server isn't running....

Comment: now I get this error Fetch.jsx:15 POST http://localhost:4000/users/login?userName=owendani1964&password=dad84 net::ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED

Comment: I get can not read property password of undefind

Comment: @Farasi78 That error indicates that particular URL doesn't exist.  The fact that a 404 response was received indicates the server *is* running and *is* reachable.

Comment: @Amy, it says 'safari can't connect to the server localhost'.  Did you look at the screenshot?

Comment: @Farasi78 No, it was unclear which error you referred to in your comment.  I assumed the referrent error was the previous comment about 404, the one you replied to.

Comment: @Amy, if you follow the link it clearly says 'cannot connect to the server localhost' which doesn't seem like a 404 error, even though OP says it is.

Comment: now I get can not read property of password of undefined

Comment: Can you please do a screenshot of your console.log()?

Comment: TypeError: Cannot read property 'password' of undefined
    at Query.<anonymous> (D:\VSCode\bgtracker\routes\users.js:26:48)